# Same source, different env. Why can't read same js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm making Rails app.
Despite of same program source, it seems like different js reading between local pc and staging.

Here's the result.

[image: Staging]

[image: Local]

SourceCode is like this.
config/initializers/assets.rb

```
# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( flatly.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( flatly.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( frontpage.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( frontpage.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( restaurant.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( restaurant_type.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( shop.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( area.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( menu.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( product.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( slick.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( cuisine.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( prefstate.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( about_us.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( terms.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( privacy.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( devise/sessions.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( devise/registrations.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( knowledge_sprouts.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( knowledge_sprouts.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( users.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( users/registrations.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.tagit.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( tag-it.js )
```

Also here's application.js
/app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require tag-it
//= require bootstrap
//= require gmaps/google
//= require ahoy
//= require underscore
//= require knowledge_sprout
```

LocalPC and Staging are totally same except for environmental valuable.
What's the problem? Any idea?

[Appendix]

**Rails -v**

> Rails 4.2.3(Both same)

**Ruby -v**

> (local)ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]
>   (Staging)ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Usually the difference is that in staging your assets are precompiled and locally they are not, which I think is what is happening now. Also - why do you need to add so many files to assets.rb ? usually you do that if you want either of 1) several manifest files 2) assets for specific actions . I'm not sure either is your case, so you can just remove them from assets.rb and include them in application.js and application.css

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just because my app can't read properly necessary js/css files. That's why I wrote them to asset.rb. But as far as your comment, I stand corrected. Let me check if it work.